# Convergence of the series with compactly supported Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, fourier-series, analytic-number-theory

Let $h $ be an even, real-valued test function $\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ in the Schwartz class such that $\widehat h$ has compact support in $[-1,1]$. What can we say about the convergence of the series $ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} h(M(t+n))$ from the conditions on $h$, where $M$ is a positive integer and $t\in [0,1)$? Is there a value of $t$ for which the series is divergent?
If we assume $h$ to be in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, then the result is true by Poisson summation formula. I can't show this from the given conditions on $h$.

Comment: Does $\widehat f$ mean $\widehat h$?  In this case it is true since $|h(x)|\le C_n(1+|x|)^{-n}$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks, edited. Does the function $h$ also belong to $L^{1}$?

Comment: Sure any function from the Shwartz class belongs to $L^1$.

Comment: So $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} h(M(t+n))$ is a smooth $1$-periodic function

Comment: Does the theorem hold if we remove the condition h is in Schwartz class?

Comment: If $\widehat h$  has compact support then $h$ is from the Schwartz class.